# How to get the response code form the following

Tags: php, xml, soap

I need to get the ResponseCode and ResponseDescription I am using PHP

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ProcessPaymentResponse xmlns="https://services.incard.com.au">
      <ProcessPaymentResult>
        <ResponseCode>string</ResponseCode>
        <ResponseDescription>string</ResponseDescription>
      </ProcessPaymentResult>
    </ProcessPaymentResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: How are you getting that? Are you using a soap client? Is it in a file? Please provide more info...

Comment: https://services.incard.com.au/telechoicetransservice.asmx?op=ProcessPayment

Comment: Are you receiving this data as a soap call or xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ProcessPaymentResponse xmlns="https://services.incard.com.au">
      <ProcessPaymentResult>
        <ResponseCode>string</ResponseCode>
        <ResponseDescription>string</ResponseDescription>
      </ProcessPaymentResult>
    </ProcessPaymentResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string( $str );
$xml->registerXPathNamespace( 'soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' );
$result = $xml->xpath('//soap:Body');

foreach ($result as $body) {
  echo $body->ProcessPaymentResponse->ProcessPaymentResult->ResponseCode . "<br />";
  echo $body->ProcessPaymentResponse->ProcessPaymentResult->ResponseDescription . "<br />";
}
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Getting this error Fatal error: Call to a member function registerXPathNamespace() on a non-object in /home/gateway/public_html/index.php on line 83

Comment: I am running this exact code on my machine and am getting the data in `ResponseCode` and `ResponseDescription` nodes. Weird!

Answer (score 0):

you need php xml parser.

use `simplexml`

more info here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples.php

Comment: I know that but what is the way to do it is it [soap::Envelope][soap:Body][ProcessPaymentResponse][ProcessPaymentResult][ResponseCode]

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the [php SoapClient](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponseheaders.php), assuming they are exposing a SOAP service to 
you.

Failing that there are several other things you can do:

1. Use XPath to grab the values:
   http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php
2. Use one of php's XML parsing functions to parse the XML and grab the values: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php

Answer (score 0):

in

new .xml put your xml data then do the code below if you want single field of data

```
 <?php

$file="new.xml";

function contents($parser, $data){ 
    echo $data; 
} 

function startTag($parser, $data){ 
    echo "<b>"; 
} 

function endTag($parser, $data){ 
    echo "</b><br />"; 
} 

$xml_parser = xml_parser_create(); 

xml_set_element_handler($xml_parser, "startTag", "endTag"); 

xml_set_character_data_handler($xml_parser, "contents"); 

$fp = fopen($file, "r"); 

$data = fread($fp, 80000); 

if(!(xml_parse($xml_parser, $data, feof($fp)))){ 
    die("Error on line " . xml_get_current_line_number($xml_parser)); 
} 

xml_parser_free($xml_parser); 

fclose($fp); 

$xml = simplexml_load_string( $data);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace( 'soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' );
$result = $xml->xpath('//soap:Body');

foreach ($result as $body) {
  echo $body->ProcessPaymentResponse->ProcessPaymentResult->ResponseCode . "<br />";
  echo $body->ProcessPaymentResponse->ProcessPaymentResult->ResponseDescription . "<br />";
}
?>
```

if you want n number of data try this

```
<?php
$file="new.xml";

function contents($parser, $data){ 
    echo $data; 
} 

function startTag($parser, $data){ 
    echo "<b>"; 
} 

function endTag($parser, $data){ 
    echo "</b><br />"; 
} 

$xml_parser = xml_parser_create(); 

xml_set_element_handler($xml_parser, "startTag", "endTag"); 

xml_set_character_data_handler($xml_parser, "contents"); 

$fp = fopen($file, "r"); 

$data = fread($fp, 80000); 

if(!(xml_parse($xml_parser, $data, feof($fp)))){ 
    die("Error on line " . xml_get_current_line_number($xml_parser)); 
} 

xml_parser_free($xml_parser); 

fclose($fp); 
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($data); 
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('soap:Envelope', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
    foreach ($xml->xpath('//soap:Envelope:ResponseCode') as $item) {
        echo (string) $item; 
    }
    foreach ($xml->xpath('//soap:Envelope:ResponseDescription') as $item) {
        echo (string) $item; 
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Getting this error Fatal error: Call to a member function registerXPathNamespace() on a non-object in /home/gateway/public_html/index.php on line 83

Comment: i tried this working ,you can check both the scenario works fine